# GRAILS Spring Security Plugins

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails, spring-security, spring-ldap

I am using spring security plugin for my grails app, but I have a requirement to pre-process the username before authentication, for example if user enters "domain\username", I only need to remove domain.

I am using these plugins

```
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"
    compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2"
```

Also, I cannot add a custom form, I need to use basic auth for this.Thanks.

Comment: Do I need to override any filter methods?

Comment: you could override UserDetailsService

Comment: For a custom Form you just need to override  the `LoginController` and the views of the security plugin

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but I can give you a glimpse of what you need to do.

The LoginController doesn't handle the HTTP POST that comes from the login form. As you can see in the auth method [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/LoginController.groovy), the HTTP POST url comes from a configuration entry. The URL is probably /j_spring_security_check. That URL corresponds to a Spring Security filter, not a Grails controller method. Essentially, you'll need to set up a filter that intercepts /j_spring_security_check and strips off the domain from the username.

There's plenty to learn about these filters. I'm still figuring it all out, but a good resource is the [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/pdf/springsecurity.pdf). The Twitter Auth plugin subclasses [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html), implements [attemptAuthentication()](https://github.com/splix/grails-spring-security-twitter/blob/master/src/groovy/com/the6hours/grails/springsecurity/twitter/TwitterAuthFilter.groovy), and then [registers](https://github.com/splix/grails-spring-security-twitter/blob/master/SpringSecurityTwitterGrailsPlugin.groovy) the filter using *SpringSecurityUtils.registerFilter()*.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by overriding BasicAuthenticationFilter and change the doFilter() method to customized method based on my needs.